# Moving value out of closure because of threading

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am playing around with multithreaded Rust after learning about it in C++. However Rust's borrowing seems to make it difficult to have an equivalent to `waitpid` and returning values from child threads.

My current implementation uses crossbeam:

```
let half = array.len() / 2;
let whole = array.len();
let mut left_half = array[0 .. half].to_vec();
let mut right_half = array[half .. whole].to_vec();
crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
    parts.push(scope.spawn(move || i32_merge_sort(&mut left_half)));
    parts.push(scope.spawn(move || i32_merge_sort(&mut right_half)));
});
```

I get the following error due to the closure and the values in the spawned threads not being waited for properly:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `left_half`
  --> src\main.rs:39:22
   |
29 |         crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
   |                          ------- value moved (into closure) here
...
39 |         while left < left_half.len() && right < right_half.len() {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `left_half` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I have not been able to find a concise explanation on how to do this sort of multi-threading, which I for one don't think is a strange use case.

Comment: Your error refers to a line of code (`while left < left_half.len()`) which you haven't provided, as well as other variables (`parts`). *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.* Please review how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have code after the scope call, which is operating on the vector. Unfortunately, the scope is taking ownership of the vector, so it can't.

You can fix it by rebinding it as a mutable reference, which will be released at the end of the scope normally:

```rust
let mut left_half = array[0 .. half].to_vec();
let mut right_half = array[half .. whole].to_vec();
let left_half = &mut left_half;
let right_half = &mut right_half;
crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
    parts.push(scope.spawn(move || i32_merge_sort(left_half)));
    parts.push(scope.spawn(move || i32_merge_sort(right_half)));
});
```